# Terraform: How to combine maps with lists into single map output by common key

Tags: list, function, terraform, output, transformation

I have my brain broken.
Does anyone can help me with Terraform Output transformation?
I have:

```
locals {
  idpath = map {
    bas = ["basp”, "baas”]
    das = ["dasp”]
    fas = ["fasp”, "fggf”, “”ffdsaf”, “sdfs”]
  }
  idarn = map {
    bas =  "arn1"
    das =  "arn2"
    fas =  "arn3"
  }
}
```

I need to get this output map using Terraform expressions (by common key, like bas, das, fas and others (list is not defined):

```
output 
    map { 
        “arn1” = “basp”
        “arn1” = “baas”
        “arn2” = “dasp”
        “arn3” = …….
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried to write any TF code for that?

Comment: It isn't possible for a map to have two elements with the same key, so exactly what you showed here isn't possible. If you can show a more complete and realistic example -- ideally something you already tried and the result you saw when you tried to apply it -- it's more likely that someone will be able to answer the question.

Comment: Solution was implemented (a bit different, but fulfill requirements):
locals {
  tmp_map = transpose({
    for k, v in var.tgs_ids_arns : v => var.idpath[k]
  })
  tmp_map2 = {
  for k, v in local.tmp_map : k => (element(v, 0))
  }
}